# Logout from WireCloud does not logout from KeyStone

Tags: fiware, keystone, fiware-wirecloud

When logged in to WireCloud via KeyStone it is possible to click logout. But this logout button seems to only log the user out from WireCloud and not from KeyStone. Therefore if the login button is clicked, the user gets logged in as the user currently signed in to KeyStone.

From my point of view the logout from WireCloud should also log the user out of KeyStone. Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, WireCloud only logouts from the IdM server when using the `wirecloud.fiwarelabtheme` theme. In addition, you have to edit the `FIWARE_PORTALS` setting and overwrite the definition of the `Account` portal (and probably remove the other portals). I have created a [ticket](https://github.com/Wirecloud/wirecloud/issues/134) for fixing this.

> This is de default value for the `FIWARE_PORTALS` setting:
>
> ```py
> FIWARE_PORTALS = (
>    {'name': 'Cloud', 'url': 'https://cloud.lab.fiware.org', "logout_path": "/logout"},
>    {'name': 'Store', 'url': 'https://store.lab.fiware.org', "logout_path": "/logout"},
>    {'name': 'Mashup', 'url': 'https://mashup.lab.fiware.org', "logout_path": "/logout", "active": True},
>    {'name': 'Data', 'url': 'https://data.lab.fiware.org', "logout_path": "/user/logout"},
>    {'name': 'Account', 'url': 'https://account.lab.fiware.org', "logout_path": "/auth/logout/"},
>    {'name': 'Help&info', 'url': 'http://help.lab.fiware.org'},
> )
> ```